# Java Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, concurrency

I know that we can have a Map designed so that, using a concurrent utility, it allows map data to be modify by single user at one time. I want to know if this concurrent behaviour is only applicable for `put` operations or also for specifically the `size` operation. The following code illustrates the question:

One thread is in this block of the code

```
if(map.size())
{
    //do something
}
```

while another thread is in this block

```
map.put(obj);
```

I want to know if the `size` operation gets halted until the `put` operation completes and vice versa.

Comment: You Better change "I Know that " to "I Understood that / i found that ", typos, Change "I want to Know " to "I like to find out/ i need to know" which sounds better.

Comment: **It depends on the implementation** of the Map.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes: `size()` must wait on a mutex before it can be performed.  The `Collections.synchronizedMap(Map)` returns a `SynchronizedMap` backed by the original map. *Every* public method of the synchronized map are synchronized by a single private mutex. For example, here's the `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() {
    synchronized (mutex) {return m.toString();}
}
```

> In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that **all** access to the backing map is accomplished through the returned map.

Furthermore, manual synchronization may be necessary if you are, say iterating over the key set:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>        * map when iterating over any of its collection views... Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

Consider the following example:

```
//inside thread1
if(map.size()>n){
    //do something
    System.out.println(map.size());
}

//inside thread2
map.put(obj);
```

In this case, the value of `map.size()` in the `if` statement of thread1 will not necessarily be the equal to the printed value of `map.size()` inside the `//do something` block. In this case, you would have to manually synchronize on the map:

```
synchronize(map){
    if(map.size()>n){
        //do something
    }
}
```